# How can we "gently" tell the OP that he must improve the grammar of this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

> [How to match responses from a server with their corresponding requests?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/135260/server-response-as-return-value-for-function)

Preface: I'm **very** mindful of ['The Summer of Love'](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3836/programmers-se-and-the-summer-of-love).

Problem: I feel like the OP has a genuine question [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/135260/server-response-as-return-value-for-function). It's just that it's obfuscated by extremely poor grammar and perhaps an incomplete understanding of how client-server architecture works.

Question: Is there a way that we could "gently" tell the OP that he must improve the grammar and the clarity of his question if he expects people to respond with constructive, helpful answers?

Comment: just fix it....

Answer (score 12):

When I encounter a post with some grammar issues, I first make some edits myself to try and improve it. If there are parts I'm not sure about, I'll leave them and then leave a comment asking the op to consider making an edit to clarify further.

This not only leads by example but also gives the op a demonstrated place to start. In this case, I'm not entirely sure what he's getting at, mostly because I've had a long day, but I don't think it would be out of the question to ask him to narrow his example or clarify a little further. Mentioning the overuse of commas would be okay as well.

I'll leave a comment to get the ball rolling! :)

Comment: I think asking clarifying questions in the comments is a good way to go. If the OP doesn't clarify the question him/herself, then I'd say one should go ahead and make clarifying edits. I don't think asking about grammatical and punctuation errors is helpful. In this case the OP clearly isn't a native English speaker/writer, so you might as well edit grammar, commas, etc. for him. Mulling over this question some more, I think I know what he's asking, so I'll just go ahead and answer it. :-)

Comment: @StuartMarks Hm, since the question was closed, how about you edit it to be more in line with your answer, and perhaps the community will re-open it. It would be a shame for your answer to go down if/when an evil mod decides to delete the question...

Comment: OK, I'll take a swing at editing it. I just noticed it was closed, and I was pondering what to do about that.

Comment: Edit submitted.

Comment: Fixing up posts is an admirable effort, but this post required some pretty heroic effort, and I'm not sure it's reasonable to expect this from the community for every bad post.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Absolutely. I agree 100%. It really just depends on whether or not there are any passionate volunteers who feel strongly that the question has hope.  ;)

Comment: Well it piqued my interest because I've been on more than one project that decided to design its own asynchronous messaging protocol. Hey, it should be easy, right? (Famous last words.) Regarding the post itself, the prose was difficult to read, but the code made things clear enough. True, it was a fair amount of effort to edit the question, but less effort than answering it. I'd say "heroic" is an overstatement. I'll also agree, though, that some posts are beyond repair. Any chance of reopening this one though?

Comment: @Stuart Marks: Your wish has been granted.