# Why does this homework dump deserve to stay on site (while prior was deleted)?

Tags: support, specific-question, flagging, homework-dump

This homework dump has been quickly deleted - [Problem : Valid Segments 1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/254573/problem-valid-segments-1).

> Consider text comprised of `blah blah`. Task is to find out `blah blah`.

Next day, it was slightly modified and reposted from different account - [Problem : Valid Segments 2](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/254641/valid-segments-2).

> Consider text comprised of `blah blah`. Task is to find out `blah blah`. Participants submitting solutions in C language should `blah blah`.

I [flagged](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6845/31260) reposted dump for deletion. My flag was marked helpful but post wasn't deleted (I'd rather prefer opposite - flag decline, followed by deletion but oh well). About three hours after that, I flagged original dump, pointing out that it was reposted and referring repost in the flag message.

My flag, again, was marked helpful but the reposted dump, again, was kept hanging on the site.

What would be the reason to keep the second dump instead of deleting it like it was done to first one?

Comment: related: [If I was a homework cheater,](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6534/31260) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took care of it. I got distracted and forgot to finish dealing with the question.

Comment: [Allow me to accept an answer immediately!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47448/165773)